# `ensure` function in clojure misbehaves inside `let`?

Tags: concurrency, clojure, transactions

I'm wondering why the following 2 invocations behave differently depending on whether the `ensure` function is introduced inside or outside `let`:

```
=> "inside let"
(def account (ref 1000))
(def secured (ref false))
(def started (promise))
=> #'user/account
=> #'user/secured
=> #'user/started
(defn withdraw [account amount secured]
  (dosync
    (let [secured-value (ensure secured)]
      (deliver started true)
      (Thread/sleep 5000)
      (println :started)
      (when-not secured-value
        (alter account - amount))
      (println :finished))))
=> #'user/withdraw
(future (withdraw account 500 secured))
@started
(dosync (ref-set secured true))
=> #<core$future_call$reify__6320@7fbde8ed: :pending>
=> true
:started
:finished
=> true
@account
=> 500
```

========

```
    => "outside let"
(def account (ref 1000))
(def secured (ref false))
(def started (promise))
=> #'user/account
=> #'user/secured
=> #'user/started
(defn withdraw [account amount secured]
  (dosync
    (let [secured-value @secured]
      (deliver started true)
      (Thread/sleep 5000)
      (println :started)
      (when-not (ensure secured)
        (alter account - amount))
      (println :finished))))
=> #'user/withdraw
(future (withdraw account 500 secured))
@started
(dosync (ref-set secured true))
=> #<core$future_call$reify__6320@6adadff8: :pending>
=> true
=> true
:started
:started
:finished
@account
=> 1000
```

The expected semantics here is that when `secured` is set to `true` one shouldn't be able to withdraw any money.

My understanding is that `ensure` function will ensure that the `secured` ref has not changed during the time span of the transaction, so the second behavior with transaction restart seems reasonable, but why does it behave differently in the first case?

**Update: tried without Tread/sleep:**

```
(def account (ref 1000))
(def secured (ref false))
(def started (promise))
=> #'user/account
=> #'user/secured
=> #'user/started
(defn withdraw [account amount secured]
  (dosync
    (let [secured-value (ensure secured)]
      (deliver started true)
      ;(Thread/sleep 5000)
      (println :started)
      (when-not secured-value
        (alter account - amount))
      (println :finished))))
=> #'user/withdraw
@account
=> 1000
(future (withdraw account 500 secured))
@started
(dosync (ref-set secured true))
=> #<core$future_call$reify__6320@6bce0fbf: :pending>
:started
:finished
=> true
=> true
@account
=> 500
```

**With a bit more experimental debugging of a `ref-set`**

```
(def account (ref 1000))
(def secured (ref false))
(def started (promise))
=> #'user/account
=> #'user/secured
=> #'user/started
(defn withdraw [account amount secured]
  (dosync
    (let [secured-value (ensure secured)]
      (deliver started true)
      (Thread/sleep 5000)
      (println :started)
      (when-not secured-value
        (alter account - amount))
      (println :finished))))
=> #'user/withdraw
(future (withdraw account 500 secured))
@started
(dosync do ((println "change started") (ref-set secured true) (println "change done.")))
=> #<core$future_call$reify__6320@5b60c101: :pending>
=> true
change started
...
change started
change started
:started
:finished
change done.
NullPointerException   user/eval2176/fn--2177 (form-init3061788549693294520.clj:3)
@account
=> 500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm going to restate your question (to make sure we're on the same page):

> Due to the concurrent `(ref-set secured true)` call, I expect the `withdraw` transaction to fail (and restart) in both cases—but I only observe a restart in the non-let case. Why???

This is due to some implementation details of STM in Clojure; specifically, the fact that Refs are protected using readers/writers locks.

In your first example (using `let`), you call `(ensure secured)` ***before*** you call `Thread/sleep`. Since `ensure` grabs a read-lock on the target ref, that means your ref is made read-only throughout the 5-second sleep delay. Since your concurrent `(ref-set secured true)` needs a write-lock on `secured` to complete, that transaction is delayed until the `withdraw` transaction is done. This is why you don't observe a restart in this case—the internal locks in the STM implementation are forcing the writing transaction to wait until the reading transaction is finished.

In contrast, in your second example you call `(ensure secured)` ***after*** you call `Thread/sleep`. This means that the transaction is not aware that it needs a consistent value for the `secured` ref until ***after*** your 5-second sleep delay. Since the transaction did not do anything to protect the value of `secured` (i.e., it didn't lock it), that means any other transaction is free to modify the value of `secured` during that 5-second delay before the `ensure` call. After the `(ensure secured)` call, the transaction is made aware that it needs a consistent value for the `secured` ref. In your example, the concurrent `ref-set` call changed that value, so the `withdraw` transaction must start over.

Comment: After re-reading your 2nd answer I've experimented with the `ref-set` a bit (results are added to the question - not sure ***what causes NPE btw***), looks like `ensure` indeed blocks the write until the `withdraw` tx is done.  So to my question earlier: "Does this ***protection*** mean that it disregards any changes made to the ref outside the current tx, or does it mean that it watches for any external changes to the ref and restarts the current tx if they occur?" you said that the 'latter' is correct, so you are saying you realized that actually the former would be right.  Correct?

Comment: The NPE is because you put a `(` in the wrong spot in the updated ref-set code. It should be before the `do`.

Comment: Also, the behavior seems to be contrary to `ensure`'s documentation: "Allows for more concurrency than (ref-set ref @ref)" - I'm not sure how all this locking allows for more concurrency . Sounds different from what Rich explains here: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/vxlzONoaba4].

Comment: About the protection thing: still the latter. What I was wrong about is the "observable value" part.  `ensure` gives the same guarantee regardless of how early/late the call is made in the current transaction. The only difference you get is when the lock is acquired. I'll try to dig a bit more into the "more concurrency" part later.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon - "Allows for more concurrency than (ref-set ref @ref)" I think all that's saying is that you could get the same guarantees as `(ensure ref)` with `(ref-set ref @ref)`, but that `(ensure ref)` is more efficient. Since `ensure` only read-locks the ref, you can have multiple concurrent transactions acting as readers, whereas with `ref-set`, it grabs a write-lock, which implies total mutual exclusion (no concurrency). You can read more about [readers-writers locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) for more details.

Comment: So, as a corollary from the above discussion, and since the `ensure`'s doc doesn't clearly mention it, would it be fair to say that opposite to normal MVCC guaranties of readers never blocking any writers or other readers, `ensure` function partially breaks that contract and acts similarly to a lock but a lock more efficient than a regular Java lock as it doesn't block multiples readers from accessing the ref under tx?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon - I think the details about locking are not clearly documented because that's just an *implementation detail*, not a part of the contract of the function. I'm not really familiar with MVCC, but if you use `commute` instead of `ref-set`, then I think you get behavior closer to the MVCC model you're expecting. However, I'm not an expert in this area. You'd probably get better answers if you tried asking on the Clojure mailing list.